# Fork-Join vulunerablity for static variable java

Tags: java, forkjoinpool

Why static variables are vulnerable but other variable are not while using fork join in java.
Suppose a class A has two variable

```
public static int count = 1;
public int c=1;
```

now in recursive action class B

```
@Override
protected void compute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    A z=new A();
    z.count++;
    z.ss++;
    System.out.println(z.count);
    System.out.println(z.ss);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<B> tasks =new ArrayList<B>();
   for(int i=1; i<=2; i++){
        B =new B();
        tasks.add(B);
        B.fork();
    }
    if (tasks.size() > 0) {
        for (B task : tasks) {
            task.join();
        }
    }
}
```

// Output i am getting

```
2
2
2 
3
```

Comment: The static variable is class wide. You are therefore creating a race condition by having multiple threads mutating it at the same time.

Comment: This is not a "vulnerability". This is broken concurrent code.